# Always able to login even when password is incorrect

Tags: php

I can always log in even when the password is incorrect.

I tried changing `if (password_verify($this->concatPasswordWithSalt($password, $salt), $passwordHash))` to `if ('aaa' === 'bbb')` but it also returns true...

Here is some code:

```
function getUser($email, $password)
  {
    $query = "SELECT name, password, salt FROM user WHERE email = ?";

    if ($stmt = $this->con->prepare($query)) {
      $stmt->bind_param("s", $email);
      $stmt->execute();
      $stmt->bind_result($name, $passwordHash, $salt);
      if ($stmt->fetch()) {
        if (password_verify($this->concatPasswordWithSalt($password, $salt), $passwordHash)) {
          return true;
        } else {
          return false;
        }
      } else {
        return false;
      }

      $stmt->close();
    }
  }
```

```
function concatPasswordWithSalt($password, $salt)
  {
    global $random_salt_length;
    if ($random_salt_length % 2 == 0) {
      $mid = $random_salt_length / 2;
    } else {
      $mid = ($random_salt_length - 1) / 2;
    }

    return
      substr($salt, 0, $mid - 1) . $password . substr($salt, $mid, $random_salt_length - 1);
  }
```

I insert password hash to database with this code:

```
$passwordHash = password_hash($db->concatPasswordWithSalt($password, $salt), PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
```

```
function getSalt()
  {
    global $random_salt_length;
    return bin2hex(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes($random_salt_length));
  }
```

**Edit**:
Tried to add `return false` at the end of `getUser` but it's still not working. So maybe something wrong in login.php:

```
if (isset($input['email']) && isset($input['password'])) {
    $email = $input['email'];
    $password = $input['password'];
    if (!$db->getUser($email, $password)) {
        $response['status'] = 0;
        $response['message'] = "Login successful";
    } else {
        $response['status'] = 1;
        $response['message'] = "Invalid email or password";
    }
} else {
    $response['status'] = 2;
    $response['message'] = "Missing mandatory parameters";
}
```

Comment: You can safely remove all `return false;` branches in your code and only put a single one at the end of the function. (That's probably where it's failing, because it's returning `null` and if you're checking for `false` explicitely, this would be the cause. It would be more appropriate to check whether the value is truthy (and accept the login) and you'd be safe for similar mistakes in the future).

Comment: What `$response` values are you getting? Where is the `$input` array created? Did you mean `$_REQUEST`?

Comment: @dearsina I'm getting `Login successful`. Also, you were right about `if ($stmt = $this->con->prepare($query)) {`, it truly fails but I don't understand why, the query is correct. `$input` array is created in login.php file: `$inputJSON = file_get_contents('php://input');
$input = json_decode($inputJSON, TRUE);`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem:

```
if (!$db->getUser($email, $password)) {
        $response['status'] = 0;
        $response['message'] = "Login successful";
}
```

If the `getUser` function returns `FALSE`, say the log in is successful. You have prefixed the function with a `!`.

Comment: Tried this but still not working. I edited my question.